# How to edit file inside react-native project using appium

Tags: react-native, appium

I have a config file called `app.config` inside my react-native project.
I use this file to read configuration such as backend and other configuration details.

I am using `appium` for `UI-testing` my react native application.

Is it possible that I can dynamically change the `app.config`(example changing backend URL) file during testing using appium.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but you don't need to use appium. Use whatever test framework you are using to modify the file as part of the build process before launching the app and starting the appium session.

Comment: this will mean, I will have to build the application for many test scenarios

Comment: Or you could put all the configuration information into a single file, and start the app with different Activities or Intents. For example, launching the app with an extra argument to set the backend url. Information on how to do this here: https://appiumpro.com/editions/23

Comment: The problem is the backend url is generated at runtime. I want to avoid building application everytime the backend url gets changed. It will be very useful if there is some feature using which we can edit a file inside `.ipa` or `.apk` at runtime using `Appium`

Comment: @PrakashPandey Before the test starts, the app is on your computer, and not yet uploaded to Appium. At this time you could open up with app file and write/modify them. This doesn't require Appium and would just use standard filesystem functions for modifying files. Does that work?
On an Android device you may be able to modify the app files using ADB. But on an iOS device, you're not going to have permissions to change app files.